# Bootstrap masonry type layout (with infinite scroll) with CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, masonry

I've got a page that is based on this css layout:

http://www.bootply.com/jWoHaY7efR

I'm using the exact same html & css as on that script for a repsonsive news feed.

When on a large screen the first page loads like this: (I've selected 9 items per request from my DB in date order):

Item 1   Item 4    Item 7

Item 2   Item 5    Item 8

Item 3   Item 6    Item 9

What I' like to do is change the css on that page to display the items like:

Item 1   Item 2   Item 3

Item 4   Item 5   Item 6  etc

So I'm trying to do it left to right rather than in columns.    I was thinking flex-box but can't see that working now - any other suggestions please?

The key things are: left to right and different height items as per the script referenced above.

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 1):

I've come to the conclusion that this isn't possible with CSS alone and so am investigating isotope.js.   If all the divs were the same height it'd be possible.